# Spark Thrift server queuing up queries

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

When Parallel queries are hitting Spark Thrift server, in Spark UI --> JDBC/ODBC Server , it shows up all queries as started but all of them gets executed in a sequential manner

Here's the Thrift Server startup script---

```
start_thriftserver (){
        sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--executor-memory 3200m \
--executor-cores 2 \
--driver-memory 4g \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout=1s \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=50 \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=684
```

Comment: Any progress here?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a confusing topic.

```
spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=false
```

Try this.

That said, I am a little sceptical on all this.